# How to implement Elastic Search autocomplete with grails plugin

Tags: grails, autocomplete, elasticsearch, autosuggest

I need to implement the autocomplete suggestions with the Elastic Search Grails Plugin, but it looks like there is no support for that, any idea?

Comment: I too have a similar requirement. I would appreciate if there is help with respect to autosuggest and plugin